# Looking for an automated UI tester tool for SWT (with Eclipse RCP)

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, swtbot

What I tried so far: SWTBot and WindowTester.

My problem with SWTBot is that I can click into an edit field, but I can't type into it. I looked up this issue in google and it looks like that SWTBot does not have this feature implemented.

With WindowTester I had other problems: SWTWidgetLocator is working with texts so if I have a button with no text just image, I can not click it.

Thus on the whole I'm looking for either a workaround to the problems I mentioned above or a tool which does not have these shortcomings.

I'm working in an Eclipse RCP enviroment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342119/how-do-we-test-our-java-ui/6342256

Comment: Not a duplicate, because this is SWT UI tesing in Eclipse RCP environment.

Comment: If you can change the code, the workaround for your WindowTester problem is to explicitly set the `name` field of the widget -- this can then be used by WindowTester to identify the appropriate widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if [Jubula](http://www.eclipse.org/jubula/) or [GUIdancer](http://www.bredex.de/en/guidancer/first.html) works for you.

Comment: Thanks I will check them out!

Comment: Jubula seems OK! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I voted it up. We are started using Jubula officially and my colleagues are very pleased. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Hi Adam, do you have any code implemented by natTable ? We are also planning to use jubula, natTable is only the constraint .